# PieDonut: How can I get rid of the frame around the chart?

Tags: r, plot, pie-chart

I am using the following information

```
piedata<-data.frame("Sources"=c(rep("Fossil", 7644), rep("Non fossil", 2356)))
piedata$Name<-c(rep("Coal", 6839), rep("Gas", 804), rep("Wind", 753), rep("Hydro", 712), rep("Rooftop solar", 595), rep("Others", 297))

Plot<-PieDonut(piedata, aes(pies=Sources, donuts=Name), ratioByGroup=FALSE, start=3*pi/2, explode = 2)
```

[image]

What I want is the plot without the frame. I have seen a lot of plots without the frame.

Comment: You should have the share in your `aes`.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a custom [theme](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html). The relevant theme element is `panel.border`:

```
library(webr) ## provides PieDonut()


PieDonut(...) + ## ... = your plot code
    theme(panel.border = element_blank())
```

Comment: When I use theme only the donut plot is shown. I mean the sections fossil and non-fossil have been erased.